# downloading images from web in android

Tags: android, download

Ii am trying to download an image from web and dispaly it in an image view.
the problem is that nothing displays on the screen.
I am using the code below.
                      Thank you!

```
package com.example.citiestoremember;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DisplayImage extends Activity {
ImageView img;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_city);
      Intent theIntent = getIntent();

    String urlImage = theIntent.getStringExtra("urlImage");
          try {
              img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.urlImage);
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new     URL(urlImage).getContent());
              img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest you use ImageLoader instead of what you were up to   https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

ImageLoader is not an Universal ImageLoader. Android is providing AQuery for Image Loading.

You will find aQuery jar file from below link:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

private AQuery androidAQuery;
androidAQuery = new AQuery(getActivity());

androidAQuery.id(your imageview).image(your image value, true, true,default icon(optional));